# How to make a discord music bot to recognize the end of song or where it is playing

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a discord music bot using this code.
[https://github.com/afazio1/robotic-nation-proj/blob/master/projects/discord-bot/voice.py]

I want to add a feature that the bot automatically checks if the music queue is empty and add a couple of songs to the queue when the bot has finished playing.
How can I make this bot to recognize when it has finished playing?

I've thought adding a timer.
When the music starts, bot records system time, and adds the length of song.
That way bot can predict when will song ends.
But this method has a flaw - If a user pauses and resumes the song, the bot will add new songs and skips the current song even the song hasn't finished playing.

P.S I've seen this kind of code
voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=lambda e: check_queue())
I don't think this isn't what I'm looking for because my purpose is to make a bot automatically add new music to queue and play music.

Comment: wait does the current code work? I have no idea how to make a discord music bot in the first place, so if it does I can research this code and add it to my bot. OMG thank u soo much(even if i cant answer the question) on this.

Comment: @kidwhowantstolearnpython
Yes, luckily this code works for me.
You’ll have to modify line 18 parameter to your voice channel name
name=’General’ -> name=’Your Voice Channel’

Comment: wait whats the format to run? Is it like groovy where you paste link/name?

Comment: @kidwhowantstolearnpython Sorry I don't understand what you mean. (English isn't my native language.)
If you're asking about the format of code I pasted in question, it is written in python.
Or if you are asking about the line 9 parameter “url”, it takes YouTube video's link.
Line 18 parameter “name” is the voice channel’s name where you want to bring a bot in.

It works like this.
Once you send a message “!play [Youtube video URL]” bot will join voice channel, and plays the song.

Below link is the original author’s video. Hope this helps.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ml-5tXRmmFk

Comment: It did help, although I'm getting the error "youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: ffprobe/avprobe and ffmpeg/avconv not found. Please install one." I don't know how to install one, although found question on stack overflow about it but the answer didn't work. So how did you get it too work? Also, I know the original author, she(I think she? idk so don't hate on me for assuming) inspired me to make a discord bot in the first place.

Comment: OH wait, I think Robotic Nation has instructions on how to download. Ill check them out!

Comment: Ive tried to install it to no avail. How did you install it?

Comment: @kidwhowantstolearnpython
I had the same problem. If you’re using Windows, this might help.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObuBysxtv9M

Comment: wait the link he went to shut down, also I'm not Portuguese and cant understand what he's saying. Can you please just give me some instructions in plain English about what to do?

Comment: Sorry if this is a hassle, Its pretty good that my bot can join a voice channel in the first place!

Comment: @kidwhowantstolearnpython
I'm not a Portuguese, so I couldn’t understand what he’s saying too.
The reason why I commented a link which anyone but Portuguese can understand is that I wasn’t sure if you can understand my poor English. And following what he does on the video did make me solve this problem.
I tried many things, and I don’t know which method solved my problem.
Here’s what I did.

Comment: 1. Download ffmpeg. https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-release-full.7z
2. Unzip the file, and copy the whole folder to C:\Users\Username\Documents (Destination directory isn’t very important here. Paste where you want, but remember where you pasted.)
3. Press Windows button and search Environment Variables.
4. Below “User variables for [Username]” Scroll down a little, you’ll see “Path”.
5. Click “Path”, hit “Edit” then hit “New”.
6. Add two directories where you unzipped and pasted before. C:\Users\Username\Documents\ffmpeg, C:\Users\ Username \Documents\ffmpeg\bin

Comment: 7. Go to C:\Users\Username\Documents\ffmpeg\bin then execute 3 exe files. [ffmpeg, ffplay, ffprobe]
This didn’t work for me. Then I found the Portuguese’s video.
8. Copy 3 exe files [ffmpeg, ffplay, ffprobe] then paste them into C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts (Your Python version may be different)
9. I executed exe files again; in case my computer doesn’t recognize.
You can find your Windows Username by this.
10. Press Windows + R
11. Type whoami into command prompt 
PS. If this doesn’t work, check if you installed the latest version of youtube-dl.

Comment: didnt read ur whole message but appreciate it!

Comment: also to your orginal comment, I think you can have the queue as a list of the songs/links, and then you can do:
if len(queue) == 0:
# your code here

I don't know if this will work but that's all i got.

Comment: I think I download ffmpeg but its taking forever for my discord bot to play music. I think its stuck on a infinite loop or something, but I don't know why.

Comment: Give me a clue. I can't help because there is little information.
The best way to find which line is making trouble is by adding print() function in every line and then checking console.
P.S
Check your workspace. If blabla.mp3 or .webm file exists, probably ffmpeg is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to play next song when current song ends. Actually, I didn’t need a timer.
Define a function that pops a song from queue and plays. Then put it into second argument of voice.play function.

Here’s what I did.

```
def after_song(err):
    try :
        if len(queue) > 0:
            next_song = url_queue.pop(0)
            queue.pop(0)
            song_manager = Song()
            _video_title = song_manager.do_both(next_song)  #downloads song and returns video_title
            voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=after_song)
        else :
            url_queue.pop(0)
            queue.pop(0)
            return
    except IndexError :
        pass

voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=after_song)
```

I referred to this code (line 163 to 171)
https://github.com/joek13/py-music-bot/blob/master/musicbot/cogs/music.py

My initial plan was before song ends (like 3 seconds left to end) bot recognizes and downloads a song in advance. So that I can listen to new song without any delay. (Popping a song from queue and downloading takes time.) That’s why I wrote this question. Now I see I didn't explain it properly.

Eventually, I gave up implementing this method.
I’ll just wait a little for my bot to download new song.